# Laravel - Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist - Config error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tinymce

I have recently installed a TinyMCE package for Laravel `ktquez/laravel-tinymce`, that works perfectly.

The config file that is published upon installation is:

```
return [

    'cdn' => url('assets/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'),

    'default' => [
        "selector" => "#tinymce",
        "language" => 'en',
        "menubar" => "false",

    ],

];
```

I change the URL to access the TinyMCE vendor package.

If I comment out the `'cdn'` line, this resolves the issue - but then the TinyMCE package can't be used.

How I can I resolve this please? Has anyone else experienced this?

Many tanks.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the line in question to `'cdn' => Config('app.url').'/vendor/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',` - this resolved my issue.